# Initialize a module when it's required

Tags: node.js, module

I have a module with some initialization code inside. The init should be performed when the module is loaded. At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
 // in the module

 exports.init = function(config) { do it }

 // in main

 var mod = require('myModule');
 mod.init(myConfig)
```

That works, but I'd like to be more concise:

```
 var mod = require('myModule').init('myConfig')
```

What should `init` return in order to keep `mod` reference working?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can return `this`, which is a reference to `exports` in this case.

```
exports.init = function(init) {
    console.log(init);
    return this;
};

exports.myMethod = function() {
    console.log('Has access to this');
}
```

```
var mod = require('./module.js').init('test'); //Prints 'test'

mod.myMethod(); //Will print 'Has access to this.'
```

Or you could use a constructor:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    this.config = config;

    this.myMethod = function() {
        console.log('Has access to this');
    };
    return this;
};
```

```
var myModule = require('./module.js')(config);

myModule.myMethod(); //Prints 'Has access to this'
```

Comment: the constructor example doesn't work. Consumer side you should use `new`

Comment: How does one do this with the `import` format instead?