# How to create a Node JS constructor to initialize a callback function

Tags: node.js, module

I am new to Node JS + Javascript. I have a module where I expect it to work as a constructor and initialize some data. And expect those data(array) to be available when I require it from another module. I referred couple of stackoverflow questions and couldn't figure it out. 
I have mentioned those links below. Appreciate if anyone can help to resolve this.

[Initialize a module when it's required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777705/initialize-a-module-when-its-required)

[Node.js - use of module.exports as a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534702/node-js-use-of-module-exports-as-a-constructor)

```html
var answers = function() {
 this.getAnswers = function(callback) {
  conversations.getRequestData(function(conArr) {
   var results = [];
   // some code here
   callback(results);
  });
 }
}

module.exports = answers
```

Comment: So you want the module to work like a singleton?

Comment: yes. is it possible?

Comment: I want the array to be ready when I require the above module.

Comment: Which version of nodejs are you using? Why not use classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your independent module with callback function and getting the output in other file:

```
//test.js
exports.answers = function(callback){
    conversations.getRequestData(function(err,result){
         if(!err){
             callback(result);
         }else{
             callback(err);
         }
    }
}

//main.js
var test = requires('./test');
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/testing_exports',
    handler: function (req, reply) {
        test.answers(function(resp){
            console.log(resp); // your callback result
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: exports.answers = function() {
 var results = this.getAnswers(function(answers){
  return answers;
 })
 return results;
}

Comment: why didn't it work? what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: It works when you hard code the values like var results = ['as','df'];. But when calling the call back function to get data It throws this.getAnswers is not a function.

Comment: I have edited my answer so pls check if thats what you want

Comment: Well i don't know whats the problem in calling the export function. Thats the way exports are supposed to be in node.js. Even if you use constructors, at some stage you will have to invoke the constructor.

Comment: I have removed the call back and got the expected behavior. Thanks alot for the information. It helped me alot !

Answer (score -1):

You can use classes in Node.js. To achieve that your class acts as a singleton, initialize it in module.exports.

```
class Answers {
    constructor(){
        //...
    }

    getAnswers(callback) {
        conversations.getRequestData(function(conArr) {
            var results = [];
            // some code here
            return callback(results);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new Answers();
```